# Provisioning profile shows on Xcode but not on Apple Dev portal

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, google-fabric

I am having a problem with distributing an app using Fabric. I don't understand what is happening.

On Xcode General tab: 
- The name of the team is correct "My Company Name"
- The provisioning profile is correct, it matches the correct bundle ID

**I am able to distribute it with Fabric** without a problem with this provisioning profile and bundle id

However when I login to my company's Apple Dev account( I am a member) the provisioning profile is not there so I can't add the UDID of a new user. I can see all the other provisioning profiles for my company.

This app is for a client of my company. It's possible that the app is under their account I guess but it doesn't make sense to me as in Xcode the provisioning profile shows that it is signed by my company.

If I go to Xcode -> Preferences -> Account I actually see an account for the client. I guess that means that I had their credentials at some point(I have no recollection of that) but again... the current provisioning profile is signed with my company's name, not the client's. And if I use the client's account on Xcode it asks me to change the bundle id because it's already taken.

I am confused. What could be happening?

Comment: i think your a member ,not an admin of here apple dev account...

Comment: My role is actually "developer" right now on my company's account but I should be able to see all the provisioning profiles at least. And I do see them but this particular one is not listed there.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the app was using a Xcode Managed Profile, that's why the Provisioning profile wasn't listed in the Apple Dev Portal.

The solution is to add the udid's to the Apple Dev Portal and re-download all the Provisioning Profiles.